# Why does LWAAuthorizationSigner fail with 'Error getting LWA Access Token' on my machine?

Tags: c#, amazon-selling-partner-api

Amazon SP-API LWAAuthorizationSigner no longer works on my develop machine. The below code fails with 'Error getting LWA Access Token' in Amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA.LWAClient.GetAccessToken(). Exception thrown is "JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

```
public static IRestRequest SignWithAccessToken(IRestRequest restRequest, string LWA_clientId, string LWA_clientSecret, string refreshToken)
{
    LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials = new LWAAuthorizationCredentials
    {
        ClientId = LWA_clientId,
        ClientSecret = LWA_clientSecret,
        Endpoint = new Uri("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"),
        RefreshToken = refreshToken
    };

    return new LWAAuthorizationSigner(lwaAuthorizationCredentials).Sign(restRequest);
}
```

I run a process that updates shipping on Amazon. The executable is stored on another computer and I run it through a shared drive on my machine. When running on my machine I get the error, but if I log into the other computer and run it locally it runs to completion with no errors. I have been running this process daily for the past 8 months without issue. One day it worked the next it didn't.

Any advice on finding out with the issue is?

Comment: It seems you're getting HTML back instead of JSON. See if you somehow can see what that document contains in order to find the cause of the error.